# How to check if a variable has certain symbols in React?

Tags: reactjs, string, date, int, startswith

A new React developer here!

I'm trying to check if my array's dates have certain symbols in them e.g. `"2019"` or `"-11-"`. I need to see if the array[i] doesn't have a date to add the inputted date to that slot. I could use `!== undefined` or `isNaN`, but it gives a number or `empty` as an error for some reason...

I've tried many different approaches, but I feel like this could be the way to go. Unless someone else figures out a better solution that is :D

Thanks for your time ^_^ Hopefully this is an easy fix that I just didn't notice!

```
/* 
date = user-inputted date (XXXX-XX-XX)
dateData = {name, dates} in database ("name", "XXXX-XX-XX")
newOrder[] = dateData.dates, but rearranged to a correct order, no date 
in the spot where "date" should be added 
*/

let newOrder = [dateData.length + 1];

for (let i = 0; i < newOrder.length; i++) {
  if (newOrder[i] /*solution here*/) {
    newOrder[i] = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    break;
  }
}

// after this I'll update the database with async
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using moment, you could use the `moment#isValid` method to check if the current value is a valid date.

Although, I don't find it really clear what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you can update your example with some data.

```js
let newOrder = [dateData.length + 1];

for (let i = 0; i < newOrder.length; i++) {
  const parsedDate = moment(date);

  if (newOrder[i] && parsedDate.isValid()) {
    newOrder[i] = parsedDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to find the solution using this, Frank's `startsWith` and using `try/catch`..:D But finally got it working!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
"3-12-2019".indexOf('2019')
```

or

```
 "3-12-2019".startsWith('2019') || "3-12-2019".endsWith('2019')
```

Answer (score 0):

With moment you can get day, month and year.

```
var check = moment('2014-07-28', 'YYYY/MM/DD');

var month = check.format('M');
var day   = check.format('D');
var year  = check.format('YYYY');

console.log(month, day, year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this: `dateData.dates` is the *Array* where your dates are.

```
// Loops through the dates in the Array[]
dateData.dates.forEach(date => {
  // Checks whether the date exists
  // !date: if date = '' or null or any other falsy values will return true 
  if(!date){
    date = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  }
});
```